# Does reading and writing to disk take about the same amount of time?

Tags: operating-system

Consider a disk block A of size 512 bytes. Writing 100 bytes of data to block A takes about the same time as reading 100 bytes of data from block A.

Is the above statement true or false?

Thanks in advance,
Suhas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the above statement true or false?

Yes, the statement is either true or false, depending on hardware details and disk state.

Note that modern ("rotating metal" and SSD) disk drives have complicated/sophisticated control logic (often involving a little CPU and firmware of their own); and have buffers/caches built-in; and these things make it likely that the statement is false (make it likely that reading a sector takes a different amount of time to writing a sector). Specific cases include:

- most "rotating metal" hard drives if the data being read was already cached internally by the drive
- anything where the physical sector size is larger than the logical sector size (e.g. where disk has to read a 4 KiB physical sector then modify a 512-byte logical sector inside it, then write the 4 KiB physical sector).
- anything with any kind of wear levelling (SSDs), where a "write" is more like allocating a free block and writing the data to it (then checking if the previous block was allocated or free and freeing it if necessary).
- everything that allows a write to be buffered and done later (and allows writes of a single sector to be very fast compared to reads of a "not already cached" sector)
- anything that has integrity checks for writes (e.g. store the data to be written in internal cache, then write the data, then read the data that was just written and compare it with the data in the cache to see if it was written correctly; then maybe flag that sector as faulty and find a replacement spare sector and retry the write).
- anything that retries failed reads (e.g. read a block, check its checksum, if the checksum fails try reading it again; and maybe re-write a good copy if a subsequent attempt at reading succeeds).